# Spring Integration's ObjectToMapTransformer with Joda DateTime

Tags: spring-integration, flatten

```
ObjectToMapTransformer transformer = new ObjectToMapTransformer();
transformer.setShouldFlattenKeys(true);
```

How can I use this transformer to save Joda DateTime in its String representation?

Comment: Let me know if you would be satisfied, if you could to configure Jackson's `ObjectMapper` for the JodaTime conversion. I mean that `ObjectToMapTransformer` is based on the JSON mapping,  but doesn't provide a hook to inject external `ObjectMapper`. So, maybe you would request that from us: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is just copy the source code of ObjectToMapTransformer, and create your own ObjectToMapTransformer and Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.

In ObjectToMapTransformer, add a getter function to retrieve the private member jsonObjectMapper.

In Jackson2JsonObjectMapper, add a getter function to retrieve the private member objectMapper.

Use your own Jackson2JsonObjectMapper to create jsonObjectMapper in ObjectToMapTransformer

Basically, replace

```
private final JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> jsonObjectMapper = JsonObjectMapperProvider.newInstance();
```

With

```
private final JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> jsonObjectMapper = new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper();
```

Remember to import your own created classes instead of the org.springframework imports

So you can get the instance of ObjectMapper and then configure ObjectMapper

```
    JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> jsonObjectMapper = transformer.getJsonObjectMapper();
    if(jsonObjectMapper instanceof Jackson2JsonObjectMapper){
        System.out.println("Configuring ObjectToMapTransformer Jackson2JsonObjectMapper");
        Jackson2JsonObjectMapper jackson2JsonObjectMapper = (Jackson2JsonObjectMapper)jsonObjectMapper;
        ObjectMapper mapper = jackson2JsonObjectMapper.getObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    }
```